# Is my computer compatible with hdmi 2.0?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi

I'm using an older Computer is not fast enough, also I'm not very familiar with Computers, but I assume that to solve the issue following information should help.

GPU: Intel HD graphics 4600

Processor: Intel Core I5-4590S

and 12 GB of RAM

So I want to know whether my cCmputer is compatible with HDMI 2.0, as I want to buy a new monitor. It's the Samsung Space 27 inch, and if it is compatible with HDMI 2.0, I was also wondering if I can even use the 144hz and QHD with this computer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPU Intel HD Graphics 4600 is integrated in the [Intel i5-4590S](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80816/intel-core-i5-4590s-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz.html) CPU.

According to the linked specifications it has **HDMI 1.4** supporting resolutions up to **4096x2304@24Hz**.

Any monitor supporting HDMI2.0 will also support 1.4. The maximum resolution and frequency are determined both by the graphics card/chipset and the monitor.

Comment: Is there any way for me to increase the 24hz to the maximum of 144hz of the monitor?

Comment: No, there isn't. Lower resolutions may enable higher refresh frequencies but that's all. In any case, the correct resolution to use is always the monitor's native resolution.